# How to display custom text for a specific category in pie chart tool tip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a pie chart and I want to display custom text specifically for a specific category when the user hovers over the category.

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/mewohraz/1/

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.custom} (point.category == 'Internet Explorer) ? 'display customtext'
},
```

e.g when the user hovers over Internet Explorer, I want to display a bullet list of versions. The text will be hard coded so it's not coming from data series.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user the `formatter` function of the tooltip option to defined your own text :
[tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function(){
        if(this.point.name == "Internet Explorer")
            return "my custom text" ;
        else
            return '<span style="color: ' + this.point.color + '">' + this.point.name + '</span><br/>' + this.point.custom ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.